# Merge Map data within an Array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, reduce

Here is my current Array looks like:

```
{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'DADA', type: '', responseUrl: 'val1' }
```

Each row contains an attribute named 'entity' which has 2 rows : one corresponding to request and other corresponding to response. I need to merge the request and response rows, and have the data as one row only. (The attribute 'type' doesn't matter in the merged row, but need to have all other attributes). So the solution would be something like:

```
[{"entity":"A","type":"response","requestUrl":"val1","responseUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"B","type":"response","requestUrl":"val1","responseUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"C","type":"response","requestUrl":"val1","responseUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"D","type":"response","requestUrl":"val1","responseUrl":"val1"}]
```

Currently, this is what I have:
https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=FUHGQN2JON75

Not sure if that's the best way to do it. Recommendations welcome on how to improve this solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is to use `reduce` to group your array into an object. Use the `entity` as the key. Use `Object.assign` to convert the objects. Use `Object.values` to convert the object into an array.

```js
var arr = [{"entity":"A","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"A","type":"response","responseUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"B","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"B","type":"response","responseUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"C","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"C","type":"response","responseUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"D","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"D","type":"response","responseUrl":"val1"},{"entity":"DADA","type":"","responseUrl":"val1"}];

var result = Object.values(arr.reduce((c, v) => {
  c[v.entity] = Object.assign(c[v.entity] || {}, v);
  return c;
}, {}));

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Array.reduce()` for that:

```js
var arr = [{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'DADA', type: '', responseUrl: 'val1' }];
var res = arr.reduce((acc, item)=>{
  var existObj = acc.find(obj => obj.entity === item.entity);
  if(!existObj){
    acc.push(item);
  } else {
     existObj['responseUrl'] = item.responseUrl;
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(res);
```

Comment: This will not work if you change the order of the object in array. For example in object with `entity:A` ,interchange the object. Here is a demo

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-aapebc

Answer (score 0):

*You can use this answer*

```js
var arr = [{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'DADA', type: '', responseUrl: 'val1' }];

var res = Array.from(
  new Set(arr.filter(x => x.type).map(x=>x.entity))
)
.map(el => arr.find(obj => obj.entity === el))

console.log(res);// 
/* 
[{"entity":"A","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"B","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"C","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"},
{"entity":"D","type":"request","requestUrl":"val1"}]
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) for this that keeps track of all your entity objects.

Later you can convert the `Map` back to an array.

```
const input = [
  { entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
  { entity: 'DADA', type: '', responseUrl: 'val1' }
]

const entityMap = new Map();
input.forEach(element => {
  let currentEntity = entityMap.get(element.entity) || {};

  entityMap.set(element.entity, {
    ...currentEntity,
    ...element,
  })
});

return Array.from(entityMap.values());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Map` and `forEach()`:

```js
let data = [{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },{ entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' }];

let result = ((a, m) => {
  a.forEach(o => {
    m.set(o.entity, Object.assign((m.get(o.entity) || {}), o));
  });
  return [...m.values()];
})(data, new Map());

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming request and response are consecutive we can just use spread operators for merging

```js
const data = [{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'B', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'C', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'D', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'DADA', type: '', responseUrl: 'val1' }]

const newData = data.reduce((acc, item, index) => {
  if (index % 2 || !item.type) return acc;
  acc.push({...item, ...data[index+1]})
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newData)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use reduce to create a new array. But at the same time the out put should be checked if the order of the objects are changed in the array.

Let us consider these two objects

```
{ entity: 'A', type: 'request', requestUrl: 'val1' },
{ entity: 'A', type: 'response', responseUrl: 'val1' }
```

Consider the first object , and in this object we will check which key is present in second object but now in the first object then add that key in the first object.

```js
let orgArray = [{
    entity: 'A',
    type: 'response',
    responseUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'A',
    type: 'request',
    requestUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'B',
    type: 'request',
    requestUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'B',
    type: 'response',
    responseUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'C',
    type: 'request',
    requestUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'C',
    type: 'response',
    responseUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'D',
    type: 'request',
    requestUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'D',
    type: 'response',
    responseUrl: 'val1'
  },
  {
    entity: 'DADA',
    type: '',
    responseUrl: 'val1'
  }
]



let newArray = orgArray.reduce(function(acc, curr) {
  //get the index of the object where entity matches
  let getIndexOfEntity = acc.findIndex(function(item) {
    return item.entity === curr.entity
  })
  //if there is no such entity then it will give -1
  if (getIndexOfEntity === -1) {
    // in that case push the object
    acc.push(curr)
  } else {
    // if entity exist 
    //now check which key is missing from the
    // getting all the keys from both the object
    let getAllKeyFromAccObj = Object.keys(acc[getIndexOfEntity]);
    let getAllKeyFromCurrObj = Object.keys(curr)
    // looping through the key and adding the missing key 
    getAllKeyFromCurrObj.forEach(function(item) {
      if (getAllKeyFromAccObj.indexOf(item) === -1) {
        acc[getIndexOfEntity][item] = curr[item]
      }

    })
  }
  return acc;
}, [])

console.log(newArray)
```